# How use forFeature not for lazy loaded modules?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-store-4.0

How use `forFeature` in ngrx not for lazy loaded modules?

In my application, every module should have his own reducer

```
StoreModule.forFeature('feature', featureReducers, { metaReducers }),
```

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, in `app.module.ts` we mention for `StoreModule.forRoot(reducer, {})` so which injects the store for the Main Application, when we are lazy loading a route, we need to add `StoreModule.forFeature('lazyModule', reducer)` in your Lazy Module and you need to import the module in the below format in your app routes file.

```
{ path: 'lazy', loadChildren: '../lazyComponent/lazy.module#LazyModule'},
```

Then the reducer and in dynamically injected when we visit that route.